# @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true) is not considering the element as a attribute

Tags: java, pojo, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am trying to deserialize XML from a POJO. This is my POJO class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "user")
public final class test {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String attr = "help";
    @JacksonXmlText
    private String value;

    public test(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper xmlMapper = XmlMapper.builder().addModule(new ParameterNamesModule()).build();
        System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(new test("help")));
    }
}

Actual Output:
<user><attr>help</attr>help</user>

Expected Output:
<user attr="help">help</user>

Libraries Used:
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
     <version>2.12.3</version>
</dependency>
```

In spite of setting "@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)", I am unable to figure out why the attribute is getting set as an element.

Comment: Have you tried adding a getter for `attr` and removing Lombok?

Comment: Working fine for me here using Randy's suggestion. Adding the getter/setter and without Lombok works fine, it generates: `<user attr="help">help</user>`

Comment: sorry, my bad, the above suggestions worked. Thank you.